# How to fillter ELMAH error log to show only errors from current user's session?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, elmah

We recently deployed ELMAH and it's great as always but we want our various testers, who all might access the same instance of the application, and thus the same ELMAH error log, to see errors only from their session.

Is there a way to filter a user's view of the .axd to only include the errors from their session? Alternatively, it might also be acceptable to include the user's session ID in the error detail to allow filtering after exporting to Excel, if that is possible? Or perhaps there is another way? Open to ideas, and apologies if I have missed something obvious in the documentation or on Google, but this does not seem to be covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ELMAH logs the currently logged in user if using something like ASP.NET Identity or Membership Provider. This means that you will be able to export the data and filter on the User property. If you're using SQL Server, there's a column named [User] in the ELMAH_Error table.

There's no way to filter the ELMAH UI without implementing this yourself in a fork of ELMAH or something.